# transmission reception in one task freertos

Tags: freertos, atmel, usart

I'm working on a freeRTOS project and the SAM4S Xplained Pro.

In a task called every x ms, I would like to:

- initiate transmission of datas
- extract data from a reception buffer (if an end of frame has been detected)

I'm wandering if there is a way to wake up this task not only periodically, but also when an end of frame has been detected ? And when this task is woken up by this event, only extraction of data would be performed, not the data transmission.

Is the best way consists in creating two tasks ? One for emission, other for reception. 
I've not writen any code yet, I'm looking for some advices on how to deal with FreeRTOS and communication issues, as I'm a begginer in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the task block on a stream buffer or message buffer (https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-stream-message-buffers.html) and have the interrupt send data to the buffer to unblock the task.  Set the read timeout to the period at which you want to transmit, that way the task will unblock when either it is time to transmit again or when data has arrived.  You can use https://www.freertos.org/xTaskCheckForTimeOut.html to adjust the timeout to account for any time already spent in the Blocked state (i.e. if the task initially blocks for 100ms, but data arrives after 40ms which causes the task to unblock, then adjust the next block time to 60ms before blocking again to make up the whole 100ms).